# Twig assets unable to find js files

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I use Symfony 2.7. I have tried to load the javascript file via javascript block. But twig always throws following error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Unable to find file "@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/".") in
>   "security/registration.html.twig".

So here my **registration.html.twig**:

```
{% block body %}
 //divs.
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have checked the folder path, and it is okay, in my view: 
`/var/www/html/UserAuthentication/app/Resources/public/js/registration.js`

And here the **index.twig.html** where I include the **registration.twig.html**:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">

            {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Security:login')) }}

            {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Security:register')) }}

        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is how my **base.twig.html** looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And I want that the **registration.js** will be within the **javascripts** block

My **config.yml**:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ 'AppBundle' ]
```

I have tried the **bundles** in this way: `bundles: []`, but it will not change nothing in the twig, my twig template still throws same exception.

And I really do not find, where is the problem / and I do not understand.
Anybody knows where is my mistake?

And here my bundle dependencies (**composer.json**):

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3"
    },
```

Yes, I have run the `app/console cache:clear`, `app/console assets:install` and `app/console assetic:dump` commands many times. :(

Comment: What do you have in src/AppBundle/Resource/public/js ?

Comment: an javascript file, the **registration.js**

Answer (score 3):

@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/* points to src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*
not to app/Resources/public/js/*

to use app/Resources you should use:
"%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/assets/js/"

I'm starting using S2.8 and have similar problems (not all resolved yet).